# Any phones that support multiple concurrent bluetooth devices?

Tags: bluetooth

Just wondering if there are any phones that support multiple bluetooth concurrent connections, such as a set of bluetooth headphones and a smartwatch, or a bleutooth keyboard and a smartwatch?

I have a samsung s4 with AT&T and it doesn't seem that its possible to connect two bluetooth devices of any type at once. I'm sure what the coming wearable craze this will someday be possible, but I'm asking if there are any devices on the shelf today that support using multiple bluetooth devices at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, most devices support up to 7 devices connected at once. I don't have a Galaxy S4 to test on, but it seems unlikely it would only support one. More likely, there's a particular problem with one of the devices involved.

You should post a new question about why Bluetooth isn't working properly for you, giving full details of the devices you're using, what steps you take, and what happens.

Comment: I don't actually have any bluetooth devices other than headets and my car at the moment, but I have Coin coming, along with a GoKey, and am considering a smartwatch and wanted to make sure they'd all work at the same time. Two headsets don't work at the same time, but I guess that's pretty obvious. Thank you for this, I had actually never seen this anywhere before.